# Login screen not readable

Tags: release-loki, display, greeter, hidpi

I'm running eOS Loki on a Dell XPS 13 with a HiDPI/QHD screen and a external QHD monitor. The login screen is OK on the laptop but on the external monitor all the colors on the login screen are strange and I can't really see what I'm doing. No issues with the external monitor once I have logged in. Can I do something about the login screen on the external monitor?